# function that plot bar chart and histogram base on selected column data type

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a function that will return either a bar chart or a histogram base on my selected data and the data column type, but I'm having a lot of trouble doing so. Below is my code:

```
fun <- function(df,colN) {
 if (is.integer(c(colN)) == TRUE) {
  ggplot(data = df,aes_string(x=colN)) +
    gemo_bar() +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 50, vjust = 1, hjust = 1.2))
 } else {
   ggplot(data = df,aes_string(x=colN)) +
     gemo_histogram() +
     theme_bw() +
     theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 50, vjust = 1, hjust = 1.2))
  }
}
```

Any suggestion on how I should modify my code?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You cannot get type of the column from only it's name, subset the column from the dataframe and check it's type.
- `== TRUE` is very rarely (never) needed/useful.
- `aes_string` is deprecated use `aes` with `.data`.

```
chartCol <- function(df,colN) {
    if (is.integer(df[[colN]])) {
      ggplot(data = df,aes(x=.data[[colN]])) +
        geom_bar() +
        theme_bw() +
        theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 50, vjust = 1, hjust = 1.2))
    } else {
      ggplot(data = df,aes(x=.data[[colN]])) +
        geom_histogram() +
        theme_bw() +
        theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 50, vjust = 1, hjust = 1.2))
    }
}

chartCol(mpg,'year')
```

[image]